# Mass of a free falling object

Tags: mass, speed, free-fall

What does General Theory say about the mass change of a freely falling object in a gravitational field? That is, does its mass change as the velocity increases? And, similarly, does the mass of an orbiting object change as its velocity changes, for example during planetary motion (e.g., Mercury)?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/133376/50583

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is there a controversy on whether mass increases with speed?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/133376/)